# Android java make/access obj json as if it were js json

Tags: java, android, json, object

I have the following json object.

I have to make sure to keep the same structure and use it on android java.

I would like to make that doing something like this:

`obj.facebook.appUri` returns me the correct string.

```
{
      "facebook":{
        "appUri": "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/",
        "setPackage": "com.facebook.katana",
        "webUri": "https://www.facebook.com/"
      },
      "instagram":{
        "appUri": "http://instagram.com/_u/",
        "setPackage": "com.instagram.android",
        "webUri": "http://instagram.com/"
      },
      "twitter":{
        "appUri": "twitter://user?screen_name=",
        "setPackage": "com.twitter.android",
        "webUri": "https://twitter.com/"
      },
      "market":{
        "appUri": "market://details?id=",
        "setPackage": "com.android.vending",
        "webUri": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
      }
    }
```

What would be the right way?

Comment: use GsonFormat from Android studio check https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7654-gsonformat

Answer (score 0):

use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and generate classes. 
Source type set to JSON